# iOS Rejection due to Google SignIn. Latest Google SignIn (4.0.0) goes to safari

Tags: ios, ios8, ios9, google-signin

our app got rejected by apple for

> Design - 4.0
>
> We noticed that the user is taken to Safari to sign in or register for
>   an account when logging in with Google+, which provides a poor user
>   experience.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to enable users to sign in with Google+ in the
>   app. You can do this by updating to the latest Google+ SDK.
>
> We recommend implementing the Safari View Controller API to display
>   web content within your app. The Safari View Controller allows the
>   display of a URL and inspection of the certificate from an embedded
>   browser in an app so that customers can verify the webpage URL and SSL
>   certificate to confirm they are entering their sign in credentials
>   into a legitimate page.

I am using pod and have the latest Google SignIn library, not a GooglePlus one.
The library 4.0.0 (15/05/2016), says on release notes

```
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release
```

> Removes allowsSignInWithBrowser and allowsSignInWithWebView properties
>   from GIDSignIn.

That means that I don't have a way to force it on iOS 8 to have the default iOS 9 behavior (Open a safari like browser within the app). Having installed Google App or Google+ App makes no difference.

Tried to downgrade to 2.4.0 using cocoa pods but it says

> Analyzing dependencies [!] Unable to satisfy the following
>   requirements:
>
> - `Google/SignIn (= 2.4.0)` required by `Podfile`
> - `Google/SignIn (= 2.4.0)` required by `Podfile`

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to the release notes - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release#2015-09-25_--_v230 this library will use SFSafariViewController on iOS 9 if you have set the `uiDelegate` property. SFSafariViewController is not available on iOS 8, so the rejection cannot refer to behaviour on that version of iOS

Comment: But the ios9 version of my app DOES use SFSafariViewController, that's why I am thinking the problem is on iOS 8. with old versions with allowsSignInWithBrowser and allowsSignInWithWebView, was it possible in iOS8 to present WebView Only?

Comment: I don't know, but Apple can hardly expect you to use SFSafariViewController on iOS 8. Did you explain that you aren't using Google+?  Did they explicitly state that ios8 was the issue? Have you tested on a cleanly erased device with no previous Google sign in and no google apps to verify that signin happens in-app?

Comment: I answered them that in iOS9 is working as expected, but the iOS8 implementation of the latest Google/SignIn Library is sending to real Safari.
I am just waiting but I strongly believe that an answer may come tomorrow

Comment: Answer From review:

Thank you for the information you provided. However, for your app to be compliant please consider the following:

Design - 4.0
We noticed that the user is taken to Safari to sign in on Google+, which provides a poor user experience.
- Please revise your app to enable users to sign in or register for an account in the app. Specifically, Google+ login should open within the app itself.

Comment: Are you using Google+ or just Google account?  If you are using Google+ (Social features) then you should use that API.  If you are just using Google account (ie the user may not have activated the Google+ service) then the SDK/API you are using is appropriate.  Have you tried the Google+ SDK?  Does it work if the user hasn't activated Google+ on their account?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115934/discussion-between-giorgos-ath-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to make changes and get it aprooved by downgrading to GoogleSignIn 3.0.0 which has 
allowsSignInWithBrowser and allowsSignInWithWebView properties
Which I make use of with

```
allowsSignInWithBrowser = NO
allowsSignInWithWebView = YES
```

Had to change the pod file to this in order to make everything build (having google analytics too made the thing so much difficult, cause of dependecies).

Hope Google Engineers update the SignIn 4.0.0, because I don't like having old libraries, but I can't have my app rejected until Google Changes the libs

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'

pod 'GoogleSignIn', '3.0.0'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'Google', '2.0.4'
pod 'GoogleAppUtilities'
pod 'GoogleAuthUtilities'
pod 'GoogleNetworkingUtilities'
```

Good luck to you guys too,
Thanks Paulw11, he made a test project and saw the same problem in iOS8.
also, telling reviewers that other (even big) apps in App Store are usign webview even if iOS9, not only iOS8, did not help, because they said this cannot be a reason for other apps to be, and they are working hard to reject other too.

If Any changes made, for example a new GoogleSignIn library, please make a new answer!

Comment: this is removed from latest library.