# Unable to use Google Sign-In iOS SDK on iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

When I try to sign in to my app using the [Google Sign-In iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in) on iOS 8, the authentication flow web page fails to load with a `403: disallowed_useragent`. This is because as of late last year the Google OAuth2 web authentication flow can no longer be accessed via `WKWebView` ([blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)).

On iOS 9+, the Google Sign-In iOS SDK uses `SFSafariViewController` instead of a `WKWebView`. This flow works fine. Unfortunately, the `SFSafariViewController` is not available in iOS 8 ([blog post](https://www.macstories.net/stories/ios-9-and-safari-view-controller-the-future-of-web-views/)).

In previous versions of the Google SDK, it was possible to tweak the sign in flow behavior with the `allowsSignInWithBrowser` and `allowsSignInWithWebView` flags, but these have since [been removed](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release). Also, it appears that opening Safari for sign in is [disallowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076050/ios-rejection-due-to-google-signin-latest-google-signin-4-0-0-goes-to-safari) by the App Store anyway.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Is there anything I can do to get the Google Sign-In iOS SDK to work on iOS 8? Thanks!

Comment: Nope. Target iOS9+ and move on.

Comment: [For now, this policy does not remove our support of WebView on iOS 8, however we may start to display notices encouraging users to upgrade their device for better security.](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) I think they still support on iOS 8 with notification message. But in my case, I have seen 403 error on signInExample app given from Google and I have not seen 403 error on my app.

Comment: They will block OAuth requests from embedded webviews after April 20, 2017. More details here: https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

Comment: Hello. Did you mange to solve your problem on iOS 8 ? Did you find any workaround. Thanks any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way is to use the previous Google SDK, for now, should be 3.0.0.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release